# Как сделать JsonConvert.DeserializeObject?

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

При выполнении кода:

```
var sessionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionResult>(responseListResult.Content, settings);
```

возникает следующая ошибка:

> Could not create an instance of type X. Type is an interface or
> abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'T', line 1, position
> 2996.

Как ее устранить?

Comment: Ну в ошибке же достаточно четко написано, тип X невозможно создать. Ищите в своем классе-обертке SessionListResult свойство этого типа или где то в глубине иерархии под-типов. Это должен быть класс с открытым конструктором, но ни как не интерфейс или абстрактный класс

Comment: @PavelPopov, Там есть абстрактный класс. Можно ли как обойти ошибку? Чтобы классы не создавались?

Comment: Или сделать его обычным классом или игнорировать свойства ссылающиеся на этот класс [пример](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) Но вообще это странно. Обычно json десерелизуется в классы-обертки (dto классы) и они просто обертки, содержат свойства и никаких абстракций или логики.

Comment: Сделать обычным классом, игнорировать, включить в json информацию о типе, написать свой конвертер. Но согласен с оратором выше, какой смысл использования абстрактных классов в dto?

Comment: @tym32167, В данный момент тесты пишу, на это. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я НЕ ЗНАЮ ответа на ваш вопрос. Пока боюсь, что либо трогать зависимости могут быть не стандартные(((

Comment: я не понял, откуда зависимости у dto, но вам видней )

Comment: Заголовок у вопроса какой-то странный. Было бы лучше исправить его на что-то вроде "Ошибка при попытке выполнить метод JsonConvert.DeserializeObject"

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал использовать метод DeserializeObject (Его лучше использовать, когда вам не важна скорость, либо ей можно пожертвовать). Вместо этого лучше использовать JsonTextReader, подробная информация [тут](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadingWritingJSON.htm) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26383831/13940541). С помощью этого я перешёл с ~2.5 секунд до ~0.2 секунды. (Конечно вам, может быть это известно/не нужно, но я всё равно решил написать, вдруг пригодится)